# Hibernate RevInfo table Rev column is reached to maximum range i.e. 2147483647

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-envers

in my application I am using hibernate **@Audited** annotation and all audit related information are storing in *_AUD table correctly. Now the problem is RevInfo table's REV column is reached to its max value i.e. 2147483647 that is integer type now the application is throwing error and value is not inserted into the _AUD table. I manually updated the column data type **int** to **bigint** but is still throwing error. I nearly spent a day to identify the solution but couldn't success.Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a custom revision entity where the revision id is a `long` instead of the usual `int`. See the hibernate documentation for a guide on how to do this.

Comment: I tried to extends DefaultRevisionEntity in this we can add new column into the table but we cant change the existing one.

Comment: I don't understand, where can't you change existing columns?

Comment: In my code i extended the DefaultRevisionEntity and created a POJO class but it is throwing error describing return of getID should be int

Comment: @adamw: Hi Adam, people usually extend your class `DefaultRevisionEntity` or its subclasses as it is what they find in Envers documentation. To get revision of type long should we go with completely custom revision class or can we keep subclassing `DefaultRevisionEntity` with a help of `@AttributeOverride` maybe?